# Django - form object has no attribute '_errors'

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create a form that will show a list of checkboxes based on a models items. Then also to be able to filter this list if required.

However I am getting the below error and am not sure as to why?

error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  174.         if self._errors is None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /sites/site/auto_gen_subnets/7
Exception Value: 'AutoSubnetForm' object has no attribute '_errors'
```

forms.py

```
class AutoSubnetForm(forms.Form):
    subnet_type_data = SiteTypes.objects.all()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.site_type = kwargs.pop("site_type")
        # get site type if set and filter against it
        if self.site_type:
            subnet_type_data = SiteTypes.objects.filter(site_type=self.site_type)

    # create list for types
    subnet_types = []
    for stype in subnet_type_data:
        # add tuple for each type
        subnet_types.append((stype.id,stype.site_type))

    subnets = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=subnet_types,
            widget = forms.Select(
            attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet'))  
def auto_gen_subnets(request, site_id):
    #generate_subnets(site_id)
    from config.models import SubnetTypes   
    site_data = get_object_or_404(SiteData.objects.select_related('site_type'),pk=site_id)
    subnets = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AutoSubnetForm(site_type=site_data.site_type)
    else:
        # A POST request: Handle Form Upload
        form = AutoSubnetForm(request.POST)
        # If data is valid, proceeds to create a new post and redirect the user
        if form.is_valid():
            subnets = form.cleaned_data['subnets']

    return render(request, 'sites/generate_subnets.html', {
        'data': subnets,
        'subnet_form': form,  
        'SiteName' : site_data.location,
        'SiteID' : site_id, 
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You override the **init** method. So you should return it to your superclass.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.site_type = kwargs.pop("site_type")
    # get site type if set and filter against it
    if self.site_type:
        subnet_type_data = SiteTypes.objects.filter(site_type=self.site_type)

    super(AutoSubnetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You do not return your `_errors`. So it does not know about any other data except the ones you provide while overriding. If you want all you should return it to **superclass**. That should cause it. The code above should fix it.